# Creating an Artifical Neural Network that produces a set of possible outputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I'm new to machine learning, and was working on creating an ANN which would classify each observation to a certain value. I have worked primarily with the sigmoid function up to this point to get the probability of an observation (true/false or binary output).

In this instance, I want each observation to be classified to one of 5 values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. I am using the sklearn library's StandardScalar function to scale the input data. What would be recommended in terms of:

1. Best way to scale the output data, and
2. Appropriate activation function to use for the output layer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to scale the output data. For classification with a ANN the best activation is the softmax function:

```
f(x) = e^x_i / sum e^x_j
```

Which normalizes an input vector by applying the exponential function element wise, then dividing by the sum. This produces a discrete probability distribution.

Then your output layer should have 5 output neurons, apply softmax, and you will get a discrete probability distribution over the set [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. Then you don't need to normalize the data, just do a one-hot encoding. Note that this might differ depending on the framework used.